# Acumatica application version mismatch with the L100 snapshot

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, acumatica

I have installed Acumatica ERP 2023 R2 Build 23.206.0006 but when I try to upload the L100_23_200_0151.zip snapshot which is provided in the L100 Payroll Implementation and Processing 2023 R2 course. I would get an error saying my application version and snapshot version does not match.

I tried searching for Acumatica build 23.200.0151 but I can't find it anywhere. Is there a way to solve this problem or someone has a link from which I can download build 23.200.0151 or L100_23_206_0006.zip snapshot.

Comment: If this is just for local testing (not running in production) you could try to edit the manifest file inside the snapshot and change the version to 23.206.0006. This may or may not work depending on any table changes between versions. (So unzip, edit file version, zip up, try to import)

Comment: I would also recommend giving feedback to Acumatica to upgrade that course snapshot to version matching the instance installers they offer.

Comment: @GraemeLM I would do that